# How to simplify this expression? $\frac{x+1}{x^2+x-2}-\frac x{x^2-1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{x+1}{x^2+x-2}-\dfrac x{x^2-1}=\text{ ?}$$

This expression needs to be simplified. I've tried to do it but i couldn't.

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: Start by factoring the denominators, and then try to find a common denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint;**

$x^2+x-2=(x-1)(x+2)\tag{1}$
$x^2-1=x^2-1^2=(x-1)(x+1)\tag{2}$